# Shibboleth configuration in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: security, authentication, single-sign-on

Does anyone know how to install and configure Shibboleth in Ubuntu 22.04? Any recently updated documentation will be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems this is the latest documentation [from the developer](https://github.com/ConsortiumGARR/idem-tutorials/blob/master/idem-fedops/HOWTO-Shibboleth/Service%20Provider/Debian/HOWTO%20Install%20and%20Configure%20a%20Shibboleth%20SP%20v3.x%20on%20Debian-Ubuntu%20Linux.md)